# How to simulate Lévy flights?

Tags: python, matlab, simulation, random-walk, levy-distribution

I found this [code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/54203-levy-n-m-beta-):

```
function [z] = levy(n,m,beta)
% This function implements Levy's flight. 

% For more information see 
%'Multiobjective cuckoo search for design optimization Xin-She Yang, Suash Deb'. 

% Coded by Hemanth Manjunatha on Nov 13 2015.

% Input parameters
% n     -> Number of steps 
% m     -> Number of Dimensions 
% beta  -> Power law index  % Note: 1 < beta < 2

% Output 
% z     -> 'n' levy steps in 'm' dimension

    num = gamma(1+beta)*sin(pi*beta/2); % used for Numerator 

    den = gamma((1+beta)/2)*beta*2^((beta-1)/2); % used for Denominator

    sigma_u = (num/den)^(1/beta);% Standard deviation

    u = random('Normal',0,sigma_u^2,n,m); 

    v = random('Normal',0,1,n,m);

    z = u./(abs(v).^(1/beta));


end
```

The code above simulates [Lévy flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_flight), but I don't really understand why it really works or why it simulates Lévy flight? I mean, I don't see how the distribution bellow emerges from the algorithm above:

$$Pr(U>u) = \begin{cases}
1 &:\ u < 1,\\
u^{-D} &:\ u \ge 1.
\end{cases}$$

If I run `plot(levy(1000,1,1.5))` this is what I get:

[image]

Also the `cumsum` doesn't look like a Levy Flight:

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for an explanation what a Levy Flight is?

Comment: @usεr11852 maybe an explanation how this code is related to any definition of Lévy flight.

Comment: Did you look at the paper referenced in the code?